# Are there readings exclusive used only for people name?

Tags: mandarin, names

When reading [songyuanyao's answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/24282/7033) on [Are people names always pronounced the same in Mandarin?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/24278/7033), I suddenly wonder if Chinese has something similar to *nanori* in Japanese.

Basically, [*nanori*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanori) is a special reading for a Japanese Kanji used in a name. Examples according to Wikipedia:

> - 希 usually has the pronunciation *ki* (or sometimes *ke* or *mare*). However, as a female name it can be pronounced *Nozomi*.
> - 飯田 (*Iida*) uses the special *nanori* reading of 飯 (*ii*) and a standard *kun'yomi* reading of 田 (*da*)

Now, taking the first example from songyuanyao's answer, for Hanzi 費, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B2%BB) stated,

> - *fèi* with 6 meanings + 2 historical placenames + surname
> - *bì* with 1 historical placename + surname

Taking from this example, I concluded that it's used as a surname since it's preceded by a place name.

So I wonder, are there readings exclusive for a name without any preceding usage (meaningless/not used in historical names)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some family names which are pronounced quite differently compared to normal usage. For example:

- 华：usually: hua2, family name: hua4
- 仇：usually: chou2, family name: qiu2
- 单：usually: dan1, family name: shan4
- 任：usually: ren4, family name: ren2
- 纪：usually: ji4, family name: ji3
- 解: usually: jie3, family name: xie4
- 查：usually: cha2, family name: zha1
- 区：usually: qu1, family name: ou1
- 尉迟：usually: wei4, chi2, family name: yu4 chi2
- 万俟：usually: wan4, si4, family name: mo4 qi2

Some of the pronunciations above are indeed exclusively to family names, but they are pronounced so with a reason. For example, however, I believe these pronunciation all have historical reasons, either a place, or 四声别义, or another character.

Besides, I think 名乗り(nanori) in Japanese also have a reason and not exclusively for names without other meaning. For example, 希 in female names reads nozomi, it's actually 訓読み(kunyomi) of 望, which has a similar meaning as 希. And ii is the classic form (雅語) of meshi for 飯. Therefore, the basis where your extension based on is also unstable.

Answer (score 5):

> So I wonder, are there readings exclusive for a name without any preceding usage (meaningless/not used in historical names)?

I think it is very unlikely to have a reading in a name with no meaning at all.

Take a look at the character 樂

The pinyin of 樂 in 快樂 (happy) is /le4/ ; in 音樂 (music) and surname, is /yue4/

Which mean when reading 樂 in a surname, it is different from the 樂 in 快樂, but is the same as the 樂 in 音樂.

As a surname 樂 also has a second pinyin /yao4/. (It means 'to love; be fond of; to delight in') [樂進](https://kknews.cc/history/kr5rzq.html) /yao4  jin4/ is an example.

Although the /yao4/ pinyin can only be seen in classical text nowadays. For example:'仁者樂山，智者樂水', we can't say 樂/yao4/ in 樂進 has no preceding usage.